# How to define implicit differentiation for non-functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

> How to define implicit differentiation for non-functions?

I want to refer to a similar question was asked  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522389/how-is-implicit-differentiation-formally-defined?rq=1)

am studying real analysis from the book “Introduction to Real Analysis” by Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert. I learned the basic definition of differentiation for functions, which is:

$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x) -f(c) }{x-c}  =f'(c)$

However, I do not understand how to apply this definition to non-functions, such as curves or relations, And the implicit differentiation is not even mentioned in the book.

I know that there is a method called implicit differentiation, which uses the chain rule to find the derivative of one variable with respect to another. and answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522389/how-is-implicit-differentiation-formally-defined?rq=1) question suggest the use of chain rule which is a bit weird and I do not understand why this method works. The chain rule is proved by using the Carathéodory theorem, which assumes that the **function** is continuous.

Comment: I wonder if there's an entry "implicit function theorem" in the index of your text.  If not then you might want a different text.  And you can look here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem  See the first example.

Comment: @B.Goddard the entire book don't have the word "implicit" in it and I never heard about this theorem before

Comment: Some people call it "Dini's Theorem."  In most cases, in English speaking countries, "Dini's Theorem" is something else.  But some people do call the implicit function theorem by "Dini's Theorem." You might check your index for that, anyway.